# Java/Swing: adding items to the system menu

Tags: java, swing, menu

I forget what this is called exactly (I think it's the "system menu"), but in Windows there's an icon in the upper left of a window and if you click it, a popup menu becomes visible:

[image]

Is there a way to add a custom menu item to this in Swing?

Answer (score 3):

I do not know a way to do this directly with pure Java/Swing. However, you can use JNI/[JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/) and [GetSystemMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function found in `User32.dll` to modify it.

> Enables the application to access the window menu (also known as the system menu or the control menu) for copying and modifying.

Actually, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_menus_in_Microsoft_Windows#System_menu) has a good entry on the System Menu.

> Some applications customize the system menu, typically through the GetSystemMenu WinAPI function.[1](https://github.com/twall/jna/) Cmd.exe is an example of this and offers the user an ability to change its preferences through its system menu (other applications typically offer the user to change their preferences through the normal menu below their window's title bar).

Comment: +1... hmm, maybe that's an argument for not doing it this way. :-(

Comment: @Jason S Well the good news is that it is possible and JNA is fairly easy compared to JNI, though I would be interested in a pure Swing solution as well.