# Add item to windows system menu without winapi

Tags: java, windows, swing

I am looking if it is possible to add an item ("about" the application) in the Winwdows system menu of the current `JFrame`.

As it is suggested in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4693079/317266), I know that it could be possible to tweak the menu via JNI/JNA and the windows API with `GetSystemMenu()`, but I am looking if it is possible in plain vanilla Java/Swing.

I have found something telling it should be possible in [that forum thread](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1348240):

> this prior to creating a JFrame
>
> JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
>
> then, before adding anything to the frame, iterate the frame's components,
>   looking for the JMenu. When found, add your 'about' menuItem
>
> just tested, works fine.

Alas, a whole sscce is not provided, and I did not manage to make it work in my code. When breakpointing just after the windows creation prior adding the components, I see no `JMenu`. Neither at the first level (`JRootPane`) nor in the successively embedded components (`JPanel`, `JLayeredPane`).

If it matters, I am dealing with Java 6/7 on WinXP and Win7, the window is created as a `new JFrame("some title")` and I am using the native look & feel `UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JMenu component does exist when using the cross-platform look and feel. The hierarchy of components is:

```
class Test
  class javax.swing.JRootPane
    class javax.swing.JPanel
    class javax.swing.JLayeredPane
      class javax.swing.JPanel
      class javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalTitlePane
        class javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalTitlePane$SystemMenuBar
          class javax.swing.JMenu
        class javax.swing.JButton
        class javax.swing.JButton
        class javax.swing.JButton
```

Unfortunately, when using the Windows look and feel, Java doesn't know about the title bar at all. You're probably stuck either using JNA or a different laf.